# Google Chrome with different width

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, width

I have a strange issue with google chrome:

With the following code:

```
<li class="smallAds fleft">
<a href="news">
    <img class="addBorder" src=".." alt="Dialetu news!" />
</a>
</li>
```

The li element on firefox and other browsers is 190px width but on chrome is 190.016px. This small diference is enough to ruin the layout.

Anyone knows why this happens?

This only happens on Chrome for mac, on windows it works perfectly. Also my css rules don't have the width for the li element, since it should inherit the width of the img.

The relevant CSS here is the one associated with the image, since the above elements don't have any specific style:

```
#afterSlideShowSection ul li img {
border-right: 2px solid #fff;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: auto;
margin-top: 2px;
width: 190px;
}
```

Comment: Without the associated CSS we cannot answer. Please provide a demo.

Comment: please visit the following website: www.dialetu.com/en I am talking about the blocks under the main banner.

Comment: Links to sites are not useful in the future if the link goes away. You need to reproduce the issue with code on your question.

Comment: The relevant CSS for this  code is the one associated with the image: #afterSlideShowSection ul li img {
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 190px;
}

Comment: Perhaps you can make a JSFiddle demo (presumably with the actual image) ithat reproduces the issue.

Comment: I will try that...when ready I will update this tread.

Comment: The JSFiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ricarraf/zvju5zxz/ note that here it is working, maybe because JSfiddle doesn't render the viewport in the same way.

Comment: My Chrome says it's 190px both in the fiddle and on the linked page.

Comment: Are you using chrome on a mac? On windows it works perfectly, the problem is on MAC OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue in chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491328